# What does "as nice as that is." mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

This is from a native speaker cancer patient who is telling about how she has been coing with life after she was diagnosed with brain tumors. She says:

*Things are still working out and I plan to get a job hopefully and not just live with my parents forever, **as nice as** that is.*

The expression **"as nice as that is"** is interesting. We normally use **"as+adjective+as"** to compare two things, but here I can't make sure what two things she is comparing.

So, is this a special kind of structure meaning **"Although"?** For isntance, "Although it is nice to live with my parents forever, I plan to get a job"? Or does it have another meaning?

Comment: I have normally seen “nice as that is” in this situation. I suspect the additional “as” in front is an error, even though it is quite common.

Comment: The adverbial ***as ADJ as OBJ is...*** nearly always means ***although** OBJ is [very] ADJ...*  It's used in contexts where some assertion is being made that seems incompatible with *OBJ is ADJ* - in OP's example, speaker says living with her parents is nice, ***but** she wants to move out*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Although is implied here.

In this case, although it is nice to live at home with parents, the speaker is implying that she sees some lurking disadvantages in total dependence. While dependence has advantages, i.e. “is nice,” “as nice as that is,” it might be wise to have a job.